# php in_array() could not find 30.33 in range(0, 40, 0.01)

Tags: php

I am trying to find the value `30.33` in a range from 0 to 40 with a 0.01 step as `range(0, 40, 0.01)` using `in_array()`.
All other values could be found except `30.33` and I don't know what is wrong.
This is my code:

```
$range = range(0, 40, 0.01);
if(in_array(30.33, $range)){
   echo 'Found';
} else {
   echo 'Not Found';
}
// returns 'Not Found'
```

I have also tried setting the third parameter of `in_array` to `true` but not working. Here is the code as well:

```
$range = range(0, 40, 0.01);
if(in_array(30.33, $range, true)){
   echo 'Found';
} else {
   echo 'Not Found';
}
// returns 'Not Found'
```

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932362/php-in-array-does-not-seem-to-work).

Comment: I would expect `$range = (0, 40, 0.01);` to be a syntax error... Has php received a new feature again?

Comment: @arkascha Sorry, that was a typo... I updated the question . Should have been `$range = range(0, 40, 0.01)`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [jspit's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7271221/jspit) suggestion and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67481571/3789665), I finally settled on:

```
$min = 0;
$max = 40;
$float = 30.33;

if(($min <= $float ) && ($float <= $max)){
    echo 'Found';
} else {
    echo 'Not Found';  
}
// Found
```

Comment: When there is more than 2500 values in an array it looks like `in_array` doesnt work and that was the problem (you had 4000 values). If you look at this sandbox you can see `in_array` did work the way you originally tried but once the vallues exceeded 2500 values, `in_array` just returned a false: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a50de51eb0410d557fa06805867b635e82038d1

Comment: @Crimin4L try `
    foreach ($range as $i => $v)
        if ($v != $range1[$i + 100])
            printf("%d: %2.22f !=  %2.22f\n", $i, $v, $range1[$i + 100]);`

Answer (score 2):

Calculations with float values are associated with inaccuracies in PHP. Your values are not exactly the same.

```
$range = range(0, 40, 0.01);

printf("%2.16f !=  %2.15f",$range[3033],30.33);
//30.3300000000000018 != 30.329999999999998
```

More on this in [Compare floats in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148937/compare-floats-in-php) and [PHP in_array does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932362/php-in-array-does-not-seem-to-work)

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. Based on this answer your suggestion, I ended up checking the range using the `<` `>` operators

Comment: taught me something new, thank you for this !