# Inconsistent results when trying to find float value inside PHP range using in_array()

Tags: php, arrays

I've come across a weird/interesting issue while working with a range where the step value was set to `.1`.

Here's a simple version of the code that just checks if a float value is within an array:

```
$start =  0;
$end = 1;

$range = range( $start, $end, .1);

//print_r($range);

$find = 0.7;

if( in_array( $find, $range, true ) ){
    echo "in array";
}else{
    echo "not in array";
}
```

In the above snippet, it would output "not in array", though `0.7` of course exists in the range. If you try changing the value to find to `0.5` for example, it will now find the value. Why is that the case?

This happens with multiple different values whether its `0.x` or `1.x`, here are some examples:

- 0.1 - Finds it (whether cast as float or not)
- 0.2 - Finds it (whether cast as float or not)
- 0.3 - Doesn't find it (whether cast as float or not)
- 0.4 - Doesn't find it (whether cast as float or not)
- 0.5 - Finds it (whether cast as float or not)
- 0.6 - Doesn't find it (whether cast as float or not)
- 0.7 - Doesn't find it (whether cast as float or not)

- 1.0 - Finds it (whether cast as float or not)
- 1.1 - Finds it (whether cast as float or not)
- 1.2 - Doesn't find it (whether cast as float or not)
- 1.3 - Finds it (whether cast as float or not)
- 1.4 - Doesn't find it (whether cast as float or not)

I've tried explicitly casting the value of `$find` as a float; thinking it was something to do with datatypes but no dice.

What am I missing? Why is in `in_array()` failing to see that the value is in the array? I've tried without setting its `strict` parameter to true which still doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was fixed by casting the values of the range as a string as recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19932638/4484799

Comment: You cannot compare two floating point values for equivalence because unless the values are calculated _exactly_ the same by the _exact_ same process, they will likely differ by a value so small that most string representations will not print it, but they differ nonetheless. If you want to check floats for equivalence use `abs($a-$b) < $epsilon` where `$epsilon` is a value small enough as to be considered inconsequential for that purpose. See the "Is floating point math broken?" duplicate that I just tacked onto the question.

Comment: @Sammitch, the constant is PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON (Available as of PHP 7.2.0.)

Comment: @KenLee Yes, but it's not terribly useful unless you're comparing numbers on the same scale as `1.0`. I asked a question about this ages ago and started a whole argument about how you can/cannot choose a "proper" epsilon without a lot of work defining the bounds of the comparison itself.